# Is MathDOM 0.8 compatible with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, mathml

I want to convert AsciiMath to MathML. I just want to get the XML content but I need not to display on browser.

So, I have installed [MathDOM 0.8](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mathdom/#downloads), lxml 2.3, pyparsing 1.5.6. I have not installed PyXML because MathDOM uses PyXML **or** lxml, **and** pyparsing.

I then run three examples in MathDOM directory such as dom.py, infix.py and ldom.python.

**dom.py** and **infix.py** output an error: **ImportError: No module named Element**

Otherwise, **ldom.py** outputs other error: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setParseAction'**

I have also tried to install PyXML but I could not run the examples, too.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not running it with Python 2.7, you're running it with Python 3.

Comment: No, I have never installed Python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MathDOM 0.8 (which installs module `mathml`) [works only with the older pyparsing 1.4.2](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=21136268).
Here's a way to override `pyparsing` with the older version, affecting `mathml` only. Tested on Python 2.7 on Windows 7:

- Download and extract [MathDOM 0.8](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/mathdom/mathdom-0.8.tar.gz#md5=9cc9f378198b44a1bb1c9069167f1ded).
- Download [revision 68 of `pyparsing.py`](http://pyparsing.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pyparsing/src/pyparsing.py?revision=68&pathrev=68) (version 1.4.2 according to the SVN commit messages, though there are no tags in the repository) and save it in the `mathdom-0.8/mathml` folder that you extracted. This will take precedence over the installed `pyparsing`, but only for the `mathml` package.
- Navigate to `mathdom-0.8/` and install (e.g. `python setup.py install` or `pip install .`, perhaps appending `--prefix=$HOME/usr` or somesuch).
- Test with `python -c "from mathml import termparser"`; it should succeed where it previously failed with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setParseAction'`.

  You can also verify that `python -c "from mathml import pyparsing; print pyparsing.__version__"` prints `1.4.2`, whereas `python -c "import pyparsing; print pyparsing.__version__"` prints `1.5.6`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into exactly the same issue — many thanks to you and Jon Olav Vik for pointing me in the direction of a solution.

I'm using `virtualenv` and `pip`, so installing the old version through the usual mechanisms was actually preferable to the manual bundling Jon describes. Unfortunately, just doing `pip install pyparsing==1.4.2` doesn't work, but pointing `pip` at SourceForge certainly does. In one line:

```
$ pip install http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pyparsing/pyparsing/pyparsing-1.4.2/pyparsing-1.4.2.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

I happened to face pyparsing missing for matplotlib on python 2.7 in windows 7. I downloaded the zip version from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing/1.5.7 , extracted, Opened a command prompt inside the extracted directory where I have the setup.py and ran `python setup.py install` It worked! The only additional thing was I had to add python location to my path variable. Like this: `set path=%path%+;C:\python27` before executing the previous command.